# Asp.net Get value from Paypal return url

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am trying to get the paypal return value to one of my aspx, so I can insert information into database.

So, first in my Order.aspx is where people buy the item, then it would redirect to the paypal payment page after they click "Buy", and then they input their paypal account and  password to pay. I can already pay. But right now I setted a return url which after people pay it will redirect to the page that i assign, its call "GetPaypal.aspx".

In the GetPaypal.aspx my code is

string amount = Request.Form["payment_gross"];

Label1.Text = amount;

Label1 is where I want to test if it works or not, But im keep getting blank, so I think my getpaypal.aspx page did not successfully get the value from paypal.

I am using the post method
action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"

Comment: Take a look at IPN documentation on PayPal developer's site. Use IPN instead of return URL.

Comment: I used php to write the POST method and it work, I am learning aspx right now, I prefer to learn about return URL first, then I will learn about the IPN._. I want to get to know all about it. Thank You for your answer thought

Comment: Remember though, you can only have one form in ASP.NET:
http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx

Comment: you can only have on form in asp.net webforms. asp.net mvc doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figure it out already ;) appreciate for the help